# Measures disappeared with no errors

Tags: ssas, excel-2013, powerpivot, tabular, dax

I got a `powerpivot model` built in `excel 2013`. As my model grows (its 30MB in size and about 100000 rows, got approx 10 tabs / tables in the models) I have experienced problems with calculated measures where I can see the labels but the values dont seem appear e.g countrows(table). I dont receive any errors and I know there are no errors in my  measures cos they were once there.

I have tried closing and re-opening the model but I have no luck :(
My machine is 64 bit and excel is 32 bit.
I tried to open the file on 32 bit / excel 32 bit machine but still have the same problem.

I also import the model into `SSAS tabular` and tried to create a new measure which again I can see the label of my measure but just not the calculated values.

Anyone experience the same problems please can you share your solutions?

Comment: Is your measure just returning nulls ?

Comment: Hi there, no they don't return null. When I opened it the first table in the model shows measures but not the other tables and as I flicked from one table to others or even insert a new column the measures just disappear - only leaving the labels but not values. Do you I need to rebuild the model? :(

Comment: is 64 bit xl available to you?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I opened my colleagues' models and they seem to work OK but they arent as complexed or as big as mine :(

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also got the same problem on SSAS tabular which is 64 bit...

Comment: I can't answer your question, as not yet working in a 64 bit environment - sorry. You might like to add it to a Microsoft forum - there are some very knowledgeable people there including staff at Microsoft. There is a specific PowerPivot forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

Comment: So you do not see values for the measures in power pivot or in sql server data tools? But how do the measures appear in power view or in a pivot table? SSDT is only available in 32bit so I guess the issue could be the same and that memory is your constraint. What happens with a cut down dataset?

Comment: I will try that @whytheq I cant see values within PowerPivot or SSAS tabular. However I connect the model using Management Studio I can see the values. When I interrogate the data using PivotTable it also shows the value. I think my file might be corrupted tho as I open other people's models and it seems to be OK...so it cant be because of my machine. I will try to rebuild the model - it probably will take awhile :(